# How to create an .exe drivers installer

Tags: installation, driver, executable, exe

How could I go about creating an exe that install a driver automatically? So far, my clients would download a zip, extract it, go to device manager, browse for the extracted folder, update the driver, etc.  Some of them are pretty computer illiterate and have trouble with the process. An exe would make it much easier for them, and save me a few headaches :)

Thanks!

Comment: Just my personal experience: I've once written such .exe that bring up control panel, find the window by title, make it always on the top and simulate mouse clicks. (Yes, this does work.) The benefit is, you can bypass the M$ digital certificate verification.

Comment: @Lenik
Interesting, could you share the process?

Comment: Oh, it has been too many years ago, I'm afraid I couldn't find it anyway.

Comment: Haha ok, too bad. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [Driver Package Installer (DPInst)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544842%28VS.85%29.aspx) utility or [DIFx API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547586%28VS.85%29.aspx). Some setup authoring tools offer direct support for installing drivers, but you can also create your own custom EXE.

Comment: "you can also create your own custom EXE" ...could you guid how to do this?